# How to make in-app update feature work for apple business manager app (private/custom app) made with flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, auto-update, in-app

My app is a custom/private apple business manager app

What I Tried:

1. I tried the upgrader package for flutter. It doesn't work on IOS (with android it works fine). My implementation:
   `body: UpgradeAlert(
   upgrader: Upgrader(
   debugLogging: true,
   countryCode: "in",

   ```
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [])........`
   ```
2. Thought of using only remote config of firebase but it isn't reliable as app store updates comes nearly after 1-2 days to existing users.

Is there anything that i Missed?

Comment: I have written an article explaining how to integrate In App Update in Flutter and you can read about it [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/in-app-update-the-flutter-way-2f25e4a02c02). It might help you out.

Comment: Upgrader won't work because it searches the App Store and your app isn't listed in the App Store.  You can implement your own solution; You will need to have a web server document or a Firestore document that details the latest version and then you can check that in your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Didn't knew that. Thanks. Also Firestore document or server document solution isn't so reliable as you need to manually handle the version changes to show app update dialog. or is there something i missed? Thanks

Comment: No, you will need to do it manually because there isn't an app,stop entry to query via an api.